# echo php tag inside echo returning `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' `

Tags: php, echo

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"eventwhat\" value="<?php echo .$value['searchresultwhat'].;?>">";
echo $eventwhat;
```

this is my code where i have an echo where i echo a variable,this variable changes depending on click.however when do it like this i get the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'` i doubt that the solution for this is `\\` because if i try to do it like this

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"eventwhat\" value=\"<?php echo .$value['searchresultwhat'].;?>\">";
```

it turns everything to gray and php i think will not be called.any suggestions is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='eventwhat' value='".$value['searchresultwhat']."'>";
```

When you start with `echo` you must not add `<?php` in it!!

Comment: holy crap is that the way how can i check if there is really value in there like how can i see?

Comment: you should escape the php value

Comment: why is it that when i try to echo `echo $eventwhat;` i get `undefined variable` meaning it has no value right i put the next echo after the first

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='eventwhat' value='".$value['searchresultwhat']."'>";
```